# Determine all ring homomorphisms from $ \Bbb Z$ $\oplus$ $\Bbb Z $ to $\Bbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integers, idempotents

I got $(a,b) \to a$, $(a,b) \to b$ and $(a,b) \to 0$ these mappings to be homomorphisms just by hit and trial. So when I looked for it's solution, these were the ONLY homomorphisms from  $ \Bbb Z$  $\oplus$ $\Bbb Z $ to $\Bbb Z$.

There was a hint, which is as follows:
"Observe that an idempotent must map to an idempotent."

Does this always happen?
Why in this case it happens?
(EDIT)How should I approach to construct those three homomorphisms by using the hint?

This problem belongs to the book Contemporary abstract algebra by Gallian.

Comment: If $f$ is a ring morphism and $x^2-x=0$ , then $0=f(x^2-x)=f^2(x)-f(x)$: this is the meaning of "idempotents must map to idempotents". Don't you need that $f(1)=1$ in a ring homomorphism? In such a case, the zero map would not be a ring homomorphism.

Comment: @Crostul Does this always happen? That idempotents map to idempotent under a homomorphism?

Comment: @Crostul I would interpret $f^2(x)$ as $f(f(x))$, so it is probably better to write $f(x)^2$ or $(f(x))^2$.

Comment: @Crostul Since your argument is essentially complete, why not promote to a full answer?

Comment: @VikrantDesai A ring homomorphism preserves both operations and an element $x$ is idempotent if and only if $x^2 - x = 0$. In particular, as Crostul says, if $x$ is idempotent then $0 = f(0) = f(x^2 - x) = f(x \cdot x) - f(x) = f(x) \cdot f(x) - f(x) = f(x)^2 - f(x)$, so $f(x)$ must be idempotent, too.

Comment: @Crostul Ok got it. :) But only using this fact, I am not able to understand that why those 3 were the only homomorphisms. How should I construct those homomorphisms?

Comment: @VikrantDesai I won't answer you until you tell me if your axiom of ring homomorphism requires that $1$ must be mapped to $1$.

Comment: @Crostul I only know that $0$ should be mapped to $0$. I am trying to see what happens to $1$.

Comment: Please use the search function, especially if you are simply doing something out of Gallian. This happened to be the first hit in the Related Questions bar to the right, when I closed it.

Comment: @Crostul $1$ should not necessary map to $1$. I checked it.